# A Question in Arora & Barak's Book: $577 \times 423$

Tags: complexity-theory

I have been reading [1] recently. On page xxi, the authors wrote: "For example, multiplying 577 by 423 using repeated addition requires 422 additions, whereas doing it with the grade-school algorithm takes 3 multiplications of a number by a single digit and 3 additions."

The above statement is wrong. There are only 2 additions because 1731+11540+230800=244071 (see page xx) only requires 2 additions. Am I right?

**Reference**

[1] S. Arora and B. Barak, *Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach*, Cambridge University Press, 2009.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ 2961 + 29610 + 211500 = 244071. $$

There are only 2 additions still. You are right again!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu You are welcome.